# Why are some labels on my Quiver bar chart missing?

Tags: charts, palantir-foundry

I built a bar chart in Quiver where I was trying to see the value of each bar on the bar itself. However, some of the bars are missing their labels. I am attaching a picture as an illustration below. The same issue was observed in workshop as well.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels are missing if there is not enough space for them to be rendered.

Easiest resolution is to resize the card:
[image]
[image]

Changing the Orientation can also help:

[image]

As well as changing the page size to display, for example, only two of the bars at once:

[image]